# VBA: How do I perform operations on everything AFTER a specific column title?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write VBA code to look for a specific column title ("Master column"), and then to delete unwanted columns after that column, but nothing before that column. How do I write my if-statement for that? I know how to delete the irrelevant columns but only for the entire sheet, not for columns that come after a specific column title.

Comment: You may want to check this out to get some ideas - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580082/how-to-delete-specific-columns-in-vba-for-excel

Comment: Your question is a little too vague, please collaborate e.g. what you have, what you want to be done, what have you had in mind/in code and why that hasn't worked yet etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the code below as a stepping stone to what you are trying to do:

```
Sub DeleteColumns()

    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim str As String

    str = "Master Column"
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Rows(1)
    Set c = rng.Find(str, LookIn:=xlValues)

    With ActiveSheet
        .Range(.Cells(1, c.Column + 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the last header column used (assuming headers are on `Row 1`) & store the value in variable `LCol`
2. Find **Master Column**, using `Range.Find` with string variable `Header`
3. Check to see if `Header` is actually found. If **NOT**, display message and `Exit Sub`
4. If `Header` is found, loop through the rest of the columns using `Header.Column` to the `LCol`.

If you want to start at the column *after* **Master Column** you will use `For i = Found.Column + 1 to LCol`

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Header_()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update Sheet Name

Dim LCol As Long, i As Long
Dim Found As Range
Dim Header As String

Header = "Master Column"
LCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set Found = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, LCol)).Find(Header)

If Found Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Column Header " & Chr(34) & Header & Chr(34) & " Not Found"
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = Found.Column To LCol
    ws.Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
Next i

End Sub
```

---

As requested, the macro is only looping through columns after (and including) your **Master Column**. I am simply changing the color inside the loop. You can update this to delete columns fairly easy. The code also handles the event that your target column is not found (see last photo)

[image]

[image]

[image]

*You are going to want to amend the options on `Range.Find`. You can view the options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)*

Answer (score 0):

## Delete Columns After

There's only an infinite number of ways how you might have decided which columns to delete, so I picked one.

### Delete all Columns Containing a Specified String in Their Header

In this code example ActiveWorkbook, ActiveSheet and the "DEL" string and the fast version have been used. You can change this in the Constants section.
The fast version handles the issue by calculating a range whose columns will then be deleted in one go, while the slow version deletes the columns one by one.

```
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:  Deletes only columns appearing after a specified column AND
'           containing a specified string in their header.
'*******************************************************************************
Sub DeleteColumnsAfter()

  Const cStrWB As String = "" ' e.g. "Master.xls", if "" then ActiveWorkbook.
  Const cStrWS As String = "" ' e.g. "Sheet1", if "" then Activesheet.
  Const cStrStart As String = "Master Column" ' Search Column Title
  Const cStrSearch As String = "DEL" ' Search String ("" for all columns.)
  Const cBlnFast As Boolean = True ' False for deleting column by column.

  Dim objWs As Worksheet  ' Worksheet to be processed.
  Dim objStart As Range   ' Cell range after which columns are to be deleted.
  Dim objEnd As Range     ' Last cell range in objSearch.
  Dim objSearch As Range  ' Range where cStrSearch will be searched for.
  Dim objDEL As Range     ' Range to be deleted.
  Dim intCol As Integer   ' Columns Counter
  Dim strError As String  ' Error Help String

  ' Determine the worksheet to be processed.
  On Error GoTo WsHandler
    If cStrWB = "" Then ' Unspecified workbook
      If cStrWS = "" Then ' Unspecified worksheet
        Set objWs = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
       Else ' Specified worksheet
        Set objWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWS)
      End If
     Else ' Specified workbook
      If cStrWS = "" Then ' Unspecified worksheet
        Set objWs = Workbooks(cStrWB).ActiveSheet
       Else ' Specified worksheet
        Set objWs = Workbooks(cStrWB).Worksheets(cStrWS)
      End If
    End If
  On Error GoTo 0

  With objWs
    ' Find the cell range containing cStrStart.
    Set objStart = .Cells.Find(what:=cStrStart, _
        After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    ' Check if cStrStart is not found.
    If objStart Is Nothing Then GoTo StartExit

    ' Find the last non-empty cell in the row of objStart.
    Set objEnd = .Cells.Find(what:="*", _
        After:=.Cells(objStart.Row + 1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    ' Determine the range where cStrSearch is to be searched for.
    Set objSearch = .Range(objStart.Offset(0, 1), objEnd)

    If cBlnFast = True Then ' Fast Version

      ' Determine the first cell where cStrSearch is found.
      For intCol = 1 To objSearch.Cells.Count
        ' cStrSearch IS found (vbTextCompare i.e. case-insensitive e.g. DEL=Del)
        If InStr(1, objSearch(intCol).Text, cStrSearch, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
          ' Creating a reference to the cell where cStrSearch is found.
          ' Other cells will be added in the following For Next loop creating
          ' the range whose columns will be deleted.
          Set objDEL = .Cells(1, objSearch.Column + intCol - 1)
          ' Resize search range to a range starting after the found cStrSearch.
          Set objSearch = .Range(objStart.Offset(0, intCol + 1), objEnd)
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
      ' Check if cStrSearch is not found.
      If objDEL Is Nothing Then GoTo ColumnsHandler

      ' Add the rest of the cells where cStrSearch is found.
      For intCol = 1 To objSearch.Cells.Count
        If InStr(1, objSearch(intCol).Text, cStrSearch, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
          ' This wouldn't have worked before because objDEL was Nothing.
          Set objDEL = Union(objDEL, .Cells(1, objSearch.Column + intCol - 1))
        End If
      Next

      ' Delete the columns.
      objDEL.EntireColumn.Delete
      ' Tip: Replace Delete with Select or Hide for testing.

     Else ' SLow Version (cBlnFast = False)

      For Each objDEL In objSearch

        ' cStrSearch IS found (vbTextCompare i.e. case-insensitive e.g. DEL=Del)
        If InStr(1, objDEL.Text, cStrSearch, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then _
        objDEL.EntireColumn.Delete
        ' Tip: Replace Delete with Select or Hide for testing.

      Next

    End If ' cBlnFast

  End With ' Worksheet

ProcedureExit:
  Set objDEL = Nothing
  Set objSearch = Nothing
StartExit:
  Set objStart = Nothing
WsExit:
  Set objWs = Nothing
Exit Sub

' Errors
ColumnsHandler:
  MsgBox "No columnns to delete."
  GoTo ProcedureExit
StartHandler:
  MsgBox "Could not find '" & cStrStart & "' in worksheet '" & objWs.Name & "'."
  GoTo StartExit
WsHandler:
  MsgBox "Something went wrong with the Worksheet or the Workbook."
  GoTo WsExit

End Sub
```