# VBA - Error 1004 While delete range of column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete Column A,B,D,E,F,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB of the sheet FeuilleFP21.
In order to do this I use as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26580402/11167163) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32883194/11167163):

```
FeuilleFP21.Range("A:B,D:F,W:AB").Delete
```

But it gives me the following error :

> Execution error '1004': The 'Range' method of the '_Worksheet' object
> failed.

**NOTE :** FeuilleFP21 is set like that and in Execution window return the name of the sheet when I use ? `?FeuilleFP21.Name`

```
Set FeuilleFP21 = ClasseurFp21.Worksheets(1)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try to record a macro, deleteing these columns, see the code and repeat it.

Comment: @Vityata are the answer with tons of upvote false ?

Comment: @Vityata When I do it manually it does the same but using `.Select` ..
`Range("A:B,D:F,W:AB").Select
Selection.Delete`

Comment: It works for me when I tested. Though if I write the string incorrectly I get the same error (used ; instead of , first since this is the list separator on my system).
Note that Delete will completely remove the entire columns while Clear will just delete all content. It may be that something is preventing the columns from being deleted?

Comment: Now write `?ActiveSheet.CodeName` and try with this one instead of `FeuilleFP21`.

Comment: @GSerg It does not xD I just founded an other mistake but my isssue is still up... do you have any Idea of what is my issue?

Comment: @Petter I had to use `;` thank you !! If you want to You can post it as answer else I will do it for you. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Dorian - so, if you have tried to record the macro and looked into the code, you would have seen the `;`, generated from the code? Am I correct here?

Comment: @Vityata nop it still display `,` just checked again. Maybe it is about workbook properties which is not the same I mine, on the other workbook when I try with `;` it does not work

Comment: @Dorian Glad it helped, I'll write a short answer of it! I do agree that it's strange that the macro didn't give the correct formatting.

Comment: @Petter Maybe its due to workbook properties idk

Comment: @Dorian It may be, I usually avoid messing around with local settings in Excel and only change them on system level (in the intl.cpl)

Comment: @Petter the .Csv I open Is in UK and Im in FRance

Comment: @Dorian,so it means that you would not have been able to run the code, generated from the macro recorder? And this is not enough of a hint?

Comment: @Vityata I run the macro directly on the other wb thats why I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System settings may cause the error. Try separating the columns with `;` or whatevery you may have as a "List separator" on your system.